# Javascript control like Google+ visibility dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, google-plus

I was wondering if there's a nice javascript/jquery library that allows me to add a control such as the one used in Google+ to select the visibility of a post (where I can select the circles to which my post is visible).

It looks like a dropdown where I can select multiple items that will show like the elements on a textbox (like StackOverflow's tags control).

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Chosen plugin

http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/

Comment: I've seen chosen, but it doesn't really allow you to style each one of the items separately in a simple way. It doesn't support icons either. I guess I'll just have to hack it and add it myself.